# Regex split on upper case and first digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split the string `"thisIs12MyString"` to an array looking like `[ "this", "Is", "12", "My", "String" ]`

I've got so far as to `"thisIs12MyString".split(/(?=[A-Z0-9])/)` but it splits on each digit and gives the array `[ "this", "Is", "1", "2", "My", "String" ]`

So in words I need to split the string on upper case letter and digits that does not have an another digit in front of it.

Comment: @Jesper Oh, it's actually pretty tricky, because javascript does not handle lookbehinds.

Comment: Is it important that you do this with a single regex? Why not break it down into two parts? It will probably increase readability.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a lookahead or even one expression along (that said, I would not consider myself as a regex expert). One idea could be to insert a special character before each sequence of digits and split by this character too.

Comment: @MikulasDite Thanks for trying I got the feeling this one wasn't totally easy. Probably easier to change my naming convention.

Comment: It's also quite unclear in one regex: why should 1 and 2 group together but not 1, 2 and M? what would happen with more than one upper-case letter next to another? Perhaps 2 splits is the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
"thisIs12MyString".match(/[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[0-9]+/g)
```

returns

```
["this", "Is", "12", "My", "String"]
```

Comment: +1 Best answer so far. I dont understand how did I forget `match` !!

Comment: You didn't get influenced by the fact that the OP was focusing on splitting the string.... +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, my approach would be to insert a special character before each sequence of digits first, as a *marker*:

```
"thisIs12MyString".replace(/\d+/g, '~$&').split(/(?=[A-Z])|~/)
```

where `~` could be any other character, preferably a non-printable one (e.g. a control character), as it is unlikely to appear "naturally"  in a string.

In that case, you could even insert the marker before each capital letter as well, and omit the lookahead, making the split very easy:

```
"thisIs12MyString".replace(/\d+|[A-Z]/g, '~$&').split('~')
```

It might or might not perform better.

Answer (score 1):

In my rhino console,

```
js> "thisIs12MyString".replace(/([A-Z]|\d+)/g, function(x){return " "+x;}).split(/ /);
this,Is,12,My,String
```

another one,

```
js> "thisIs12MyString".split(/(?:([A-Z]+[a-z]+))/g).filter(function(a){return  a;});
this,Is,12,My,String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the JS missing of lookbehinds working on the array split using your current regex. 
Quick pseudo code:

```
var result = [];
var digitsFlag = false;
"thisIs12MyString".split(/(?=[A-Z0-9])/).forEach(function(word) {

    if (isSingleDigit(word)) {
        if (!digitsFlag) {
            result.push(word);
        } else {
            result[result.length - 1] += word;
        }
        digitsFlag = true;
    } else {
        result.push(word);
        digitsFlag = false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any ways to achieve this with a RegEx.

I think you will need to do it in code.

Please check the URL, same question different language (ruby) ->

The code is at the bottom:
  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440698-split-string-on-capitalizeduppercase-char/